apt full-upgrade gets stuck on a broken pipe
Had to fix dpkg due to an upgrade interruption, now I am just stuck with a different error every time I try to run an upgrade, "Paste process signal was killed by a broken pipe.
Error came when working on /var/cache/apt/archives/tzdata_2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04_all.deb"
Any ideas would be much appreciated. I have already tried force overwrite followed by sudo apt -f install.
